# video to fit screen in android

Tags: android, video, fullscreen, playing

I am trying to play a video in android using Video View, But the video is not completely stretching to fit the screen instead the video view is stretching and its showing black empty screen on either side of the Screen

I want the video to be strecthed without considering any aspect ratio.

any help on this

Thanks & Nagendra

XMl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
videoPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video;

videoPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri)); 
videoPlayer.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoPlayer.requestFocus();
videoPlayer.setVisibility(0);
videoPlayer.start();
```

This is the code i am using to play a video

Thanks for your reply

Comment: Please post any code to show how you are trying to do this. Otherwise it is hard  to help.

Answer (score 2):

A trick you can do is put the `VideoView` inside a `RelativeLayout` and add the parameters:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

This will "stretch" the video to be fullscreen. If the video `AspectRatio` is good enough you will have a very good result

Comment: how do i do the same thing and not mess with the aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

Use fill_parent for layout_width and layout_height in the xml of VideoView:

```
<VideoView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/VideoView"></VideoView>
```